# How to dynamically create a search query based on a set of quoted strings in MarkLogic

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have the following query, where i want to form a string of values from a list and i want to use that comma separated string as an or-query but it does not give any result, however when i return just the concatenated string it gives the exact value needed for the query.

The query is as follows:

```
 xquery version "1.0-ml";
 declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";


 declare variable $docURI as xs:string external ;
 declare variable $orQuery as xs:string external ;

 let $tags :=
 <tags>
  <tag>"credit"</tag>
  <tag>"bank"</tag>
  <tag>"private banking"</tag>
 </tags>


 let $docURI := "/2012-10-22_CSGN.VX_(Citi)_Credit_Suisse_(CSGN.VX)__Model_Update.61198869.xml"
 let $orQuery :=  (string-join($tags/tag, ','))


 for $x in cts:search(doc($docURI)/doc/Content/Section/Paragraph, cts:or-query(($orQuery)))


 let $r := cts:highlight($x, cts:or-query($orQuery), <b>{$cts:text}</b>)

 return <result>{$r}</result>
```

The exact query that i want to run is :

```
  cts:search(doc($docURI)/doc/Content/Section/Paragraph, cts:or-query(("credit","bank","private banking")))
```

and when i do

```
 return (string-join($tags/tag, ','))
```

it gives me exactly what i require

```
 "credit","bank","private banking"
```

But why does it not return any result in or-query?

Comment: [cts:or-query](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:or-query) requires a set of sub-queries, you are giving it a comma-separated string of quoted strings, which is not the same as a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used fn:tokenize instead it worked perfectly for my usecase 
its because i was trying to pass these arguments from java using XCC api and it would not return anything with string values

```
  xquery version "1.0-ml";
  declare namespace html = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

  declare variable $docURI as xs:string external ;
  declare variable $orQuery as xs:string external ;

  let $input := "credit,bank"
  let $tokens := fn:tokenize($input, ",") 

  let $docURI := "2012-11-19 0005.HK (Citi) HSBC Holdings Plc (0005.HK)_ Model Update.61503613.pdf"

  for $x in cts:search(fn:doc($docURI), cts:or-query(($tokens)))

  let $r := cts:highlight($x, cts:or-query(($tokens)), <b>{$cts:text}</b>)

  return <result>{$r}</result>
```

Answer (score 1):

The string-join step should not need to be string-join.  That passes in a literal string.  In xQuery, sequences are your friend.

I think you want to do something like this:

```
let $tags-to-search :=  ($tags/tag/text()!replace(., '^"|"$', '') ) (: a sequence of tags :)
cts:search(doc($docURI)/doc/Content/Section/Paragraph, cts:word-query($tags-to-search))
```

cts:word-query is the default query used for parameter 2 of search if you pass in a string. cts:word query also returns matches for any items in a  sequence if presented with that.

https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:word-query

**EDIT:** Added the replace step for the quotes as suggested by Abel. This is specific to the data as presented by the original question. The overall approach remains the same.

Comment: I think this is close, but still won't work, as the OP has the words quoted in the input document. Consider adding `$tags-to-search!replace(., '^"|"$', '')`. That some contain spaces (probably) does not matter as it is still a sequence of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do you need something like this
`let $orQuery := for $tag in $tags/tag return cts:word-query($tag)`